# Получение нажатых элементов listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Добрый день!

Есть listview с кастомным адаптером. В каждом элементе этого listview есть checkbox. Проблема в том что с кастомным адаптером не работает .getCheckedItemPositions(), и в итоге я не могу получить список нажатых элементов.

В методе onCreate:

```
  final String[] words = new String[] {
                "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
        };


        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, words);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Собственно адаптер:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    int id = 1;


    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        TextView newwordview = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newwordview);


        newwordview.setText("lalala");

            return rowView;
    }
}
```

Попытка по нажатию получить список нажатых чекбоксов:

```
public void addbtnclick(View view){
        int cntChoice = listView.getCount();
        SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {

            if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) {
                String a = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                myDbHelper.setadd(a, "en");
            } else if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) {

            }
        }
    }
```

При дебаге оказывается, что sparseBooleanArray состоит из 0 элементов как я ни кликай на эти чекбоксы. Что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для правильной работы списка с установленным режимом выбора `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPE` (а только тогда вы получите что-либо в `getCheckedItemPositions()`) необходимо, во-первых, установить `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPE);`. Во-вторых, вам нужно в R.layout.listitem использовать `View`, реализующий `Chackable` интерфейс.

```
<com.example.MyCheckableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.example.MyCheckableRow>
```

И реализовать этот кастомный View:

**/com/example/MyCheckableRow.java**

```
public class MyCheckableRow extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
  private CheckBox mCheckBox;
  private boolean isChecked;
  public MyCheckableRow(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  public MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override
  public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
      this.isChecked = checked;
      mCheckBox.setChecked(checked);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isChecked() {
      return isChecked;
  }
  @Override
  public void toggle() {
      this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
      mCheckBox.setChecked(this.isChecked);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onFinishInflate() {
      super.onFinishInflate();
      mCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb);//ваш чекбокс
  }
}
```

Как видно, визуальное выделение для работы механизма не обязательно, в частности чекбокса может не быть, выделение можно реализовать и сменой фона, например.

Comment: There is no defaults constructor available in 'android.widget.LinearLayout', no such instance field 'isChecked', cannot find local variable 'mCheckBox'

Comment: @Евгений дополнил ответ. Не стоит бездумно копипастить код, что-то вы сами должны уметь.