# .getCheckedItemPositions() не получает отмеченные элементы из LISTVIEW

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте очень нужна помощь , долго не могу решить эту проблему

Вообщем в ListView есть ChekBox , но getCheckedItemPositions()  все время  возвращает 0 отмеченных элементов , порылся в интернете и оказалось что нужно R.layout.listitem использовать View, реализующий Chackable интерфейс, но я так и смог его реализовать , пробовал как здесь предлагают [Получение нажатых элементов listview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444426/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-listview)
,но не получилось , что то я упускаю

Вот код самого адаптера для ListView

```
ListView lvSimple;
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            Display_all_messages.this, subscriptionsList,
            R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_SERIE,TAG_URL,
            TAG_VOICE,TAG_ID},
            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.series ,R.id.url,R.id.voice,R.id.id});

    //adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
    lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
   lvSimple.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lvSimple.setAdapter(adapter);



    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SparseBooleanArray sba =lvSimple.getCheckedItemPositions();
            if(sba.size()>0)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Количество отмеченных элементов= "+sba.size());
                for(int i =0; i<lvSimple.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    if(sba.get(i)){

                        System.out.println(lvSimple.getItemAtPosition(sba.keyAt(i)).toString());
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Delete from mytable: ---");

                        //int delCount = db.delete("Messages", "name = " +"'"+lvSimple.getItemAtPosition(sba.keyAt(i)).toString()+"'", null);
                       // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + delCount);

                    }
                }
```

Код messages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    />
<Button android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Удалить"/>
```

Дальше попытка реализации Chackable интерфейс как в этом примере [Получение нажатых элементов listview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444426/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-listview)

Код list_item2.xml

```
 <com.example.alex.client2.MyCheckableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/url"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/u"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:text="Посмотреть на сайте"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/voice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/series"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </com.example.alex.client2.MyCheckableRow>
```

И реализация этого кастомного View:

```
  package com.example.alex.client2;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.Checkable;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  public class MyCheckableRow extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
  private CheckBox cb;
  private boolean isChecked;
  public MyCheckableRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
/*@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void  MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}*/

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.isChecked = checked;
    cb.setChecked(checked);
}
@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}
@Override
public void toggle() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    cb.setChecked(this.isChecked);
}
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb);//ваш чекбокс
}
}
```

Извините за кривое объяснение,  всем буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: возможно [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464885/177345) вам поможет решить проблему

Comment: @pavlofff Большое спасибо за помощь  эта ссылка мне помогла решить  проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем в этом ответе все очень хорошо описана [При скроллинге пропадают отметки чекбоксов в айтемах ListView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464820/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85-listview/464885#464885), 
реализовал  интерфейс Checkable , как в этом примере http://adanware.blogspot.ru/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html
 и все отлично заработало

Большое Спасибо pavlofff