# Выделение нажатых элементов listview

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

Есть listview, поля которого состоят из имени и номера телефона

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="#60000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CALLbtn"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SMSbtn"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Проблема следующая, хочу сделать так, чтобы при долгом нажатии на элемент появлялось контекстное меню, но реализовать не получается, что только не делал, элементы просто не выделяются, обработчик не вызывается.

Самое подхоящее решение, которое я нашёл было [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444426/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-listview), но как сделать выделение со сменой фона?

Comment: Проблема в том что не вызывается контекстное меню? Или что не выделяется элемент?

Comment: @PawelShi не выделяется

Comment: Слушатель на длинное нажатие можно попробовать. Только его нужно не на ListView садить, а на элемент